# fetching data with useState and useEffect in react.js

Tags: reactjs, fetch, render, use-effect, use-state

with this code I'm able to retrieve users' data and console.log it but unable to pass or fetch it into the data array and render users' info using data.map as it console.logs empty array and throws out an error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.map is not a function. How can I fetch this data to the data array? Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './welcome.css';


function Welcome (){
  const [data, setUsers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/users')
    .then((res) =>  res.json())
    .then(users => setUsers({users}, console.log(users), console.log(data)))
      
    }
  )
  

  return(
    <div className='welcome'>    
    <ul >
      {data.map(user => 
        <li  className='user' key={user._id}>{user.Username}</li>  
      )}

    </ul>

    <h1>Welcome to GRM</h1> 
    <h1>Explore the music world</h1>

  </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: `setUsers({users}, console.log(users), console.log(data))` — The value you are passing isn't an array, is it? Pass an array.

Comment: setUsers(users) not as object

Comment: I've realized my data wasn't a plain array, instead it's  json object with embedded arrays in it. Ex: ```{"users":[{"_id":"622b236c06f05a8272c7bdbd","Username":"111","Email":"111@gmail.com","Password":"$2b$10$4hr2vq6LLhwh9aBcPtvc5eRKXTEcxAIBZPMPagNgeQoMkgIXQwSIq","Lists":[],"__v":0},{"_id":"622b237806f05a8272c7bdbf","Username":"222","Email":"222@gmail.com","Password":"$2b$10$8ZN9V7IgnTDwfNPiP2kiUOSnTcHcOIixf9M3mkM5knYCd9D8fIU0y","Lists":[],"__v":0}]}. Based on this data structure what should I change in the code?

Answer (score 1):

If `users` is an array, then you only need to pass `users` to `setUsers`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./welcome.css";

function Welcome() {
  const [data, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/users")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(({ users }) =>
        setUsers(users)
      );
  });

  return (
    <div className="welcome">
      <ul>
        {data.map((user) => (
          <li className="user" key={user._id}>
            {user.Username}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <h1>Welcome to GRM</h1>
      <h1>Explore the music world</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I've realized my data wasn't a plain array, instead it's json object with embedded arrays in it. Ex: `{"users":[{"_id":"622b236c06f05a8272c7bdbd","Username":"111","Email":"111@gmail.com","Password":"$2b$10$4hr2vq6LLhwh9aBcPtvc5eRKXTEcxAIBZPMPagNgeQoMkgIXQwSIq","Lists":[],"__v":0},{"_id":"622b237806f05a8272c7bdbf","Username":"222","Email":"222@gmail.com","Password":"$2b$10$8ZN9V7IgnTDwfNPiP2kiUOSnTcHcOIixf9M3mkM5knYCd9D8fIU0y","Lists":[],"__v":0}]}. `Based on this data structure what should I change in the ?

Comment: Yeah, you should destruct the `users` array before passing it to `setUsers`. I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help and time but this solution is not working as well, still throwing a same error..

Answer (score 1):

Remove line

> .then(users => setUsers({users}, console.log(users),
> console.log(data)))

Add This

> .then ((res)=>{setUsers(res.data)})

I hope it will work for you

Comment: I've realized my data wasn't a plain array, instead it's  json object with embedded arrays in it. Ex: `code`{"users":[{"_id":"622b236c06f05a8272c7bdbd","Username":"111","Email":"111@gmail.com","Password":"$2b$10$4hr2vq6LLhwh9aBcPtvc5eRKXTEcxAIBZPMPagNgeQoMkgIXQwSIq","Lists":[],"__v":0},{"_id":"622b237806f05a8272c7bdbf","Username":"222","Email":"222@gmail.com","Password":"$2b$10$8ZN9V7IgnTDwfNPiP2kiUOSnTcHcOIixf9M3mkM5knYCd9D8fIU0y","Lists":[],"__v":0}]}. Based on this data structure what should I change in the code?`code`

Answer (score 1):

for those who are running into the same problem, here's what worked for me:

```
export default function Welcome (){
  const [data, setUsers] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/users')
    .then(res => (res.json()))
    .then(({users}) => setUsers((users)))
  
  }) 
  return(
    <div className='welcome'>    
      <ul>
        {data.map((user) => 
          <li  className='user' key={user._id}>
            {user.Username}
          </li>  
        )}

      </ul>

      <h1>Welcome to GRM</h1> 
      <h1>Explore the music world</h1>

    </div>
   )
}
```

Unsurprisingly enough it was a matter of the right amount of brackets.
Here's what my data retrieved from MongoDB looked like:

```
{"users":
[{
"_id":"622c6b2e1c9e40c9775a8940",
"Username":"222","Email":"222@gmail.com",
"Password":"$2b$10$OafBy/2M6a3TZOf/Fslv.u/7tREMGJk6BD.GCiul23giaYh58CTfC",
"Lists":[],"__v":0
},
{
"_id":"622c6b491c9e40c9775a8944",
"Username":"111","Email":"111@gmail.com",
"Password":"$2b$10$cpqiLxsW70stj/4P5AGKUucvXyRDha6Fy3bpGsz0vg.1p0ia.7Jwi",
"Lists":[],"__v":0
}
]}
```